# Пути в файлах сайта

Tags: файловая-система

Есть ЧПУ, которая создает папку user, при переходе в ЛК. Проблема с подключением файлов. Ресурсы находятся в папке `vendor` в корне сайта. Но как обращаться к файлам на локальном сервере? `/` берет корень сайта, а это `http://localhost`. Мне соответственно так не нужно, как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: Очень туманное описание задачи. Вам нужно из скрипта  обратиться к файлу на сервере, который не находится в каталоге сайта? Вот так например /var/data/file.txt

Comment: хватить плодить одни и те же вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно прописать соответствующие директивы в двух файлах htaccess - в корне сайта и в папке, которая будет считаться корневой для запросов (где располагается сам сайт).

А именно:

1. В корень сайта файл htaccess:

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /vendor/$1
2. В папку, в которой продакшн и которая должна восприниматься, как корень (vendor),  файл htaccess:

   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php